# Add multi arch (i386) cross dev and run time support

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, cross-compilation

On a 22.04.03 system I've added i386 architecture support :

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

I can see multiarch-support is already installed :

```
sudo apt list --installed multi*
Listing... Done
multiarch-support/now 2.27-3ubuntu1.5 amd64 [installed,local]
```

When I attempt to execute a 32 bit program I receive this error:

```
bash: ./awk: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

file ./awk
./awk: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /libx32/ld-linux-x32.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=814da5a7561a71760e7ee54790fef0e6fbc6f4a7, for GNU/Linux 3.4.0, stripped
```

When I look in /libx32 a find that it is empty.

I have setup cross compile before (on another 22.04 system where 32 bit and 64 bit binaries are working) and I don't recall what I did specially to get it going.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading from kernel 6.5 to 5.15 fixed my issue.

I installed arch-test which displayed 3 entries (amd64, i386 & x32) on a working system but only (amd64, i386) on a broken system.  arch-test checks the kernel (not the distro).  So I rolled back the kernel and fixed the issue.

I hope dropping x32 biarch support isn't intentional.  How can I raise this issue?

By the way you also need to have package libc6-x32 installed, but the correct kernel it doesn't help.